# Atom editor: jump to CFML function

Tags: coldfusion, atom-editor, cfml

I'd like to quickly jump to functions by name in Atom.  I see that there's a `symbols-view` core package that runs on ctags.  I've installed ctags and when I run `ctags --list-languages` I don't see ColdFusion or CFML listed (and when I generate the `tags` file no .cfm or .cfc files are treated).

Is there an alternative way to jump quickly to functions by name? (preferably in both CFML and CFscript, as I have both in my project currently)

Comment: It looks like you can get the package here: https://github.com/rwatts3/atom-language-coldfusion

Comment: I love the changelog.md file for it:  `0.1.0 - First Release * Every feature added * Every bug fixed`

Comment: The description in `package.json` for that project says "Coldfusion Language for Atom converted Textmate Bundle".  But the `language-cfml` package is also that and looks much better maintained.  I do have that installed and it hasn't affected what's returned from running `ctags --list-languages` or allowed `symbols-view` to find CF functions.

Comment: It sounds like this is the best answer. Perhaps you should write it up as the answer to the question

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question, though.  It's information about a package that doesn't do what the question is asking about.